# Vim split string by multiple delimiters

Tags: string, vim, split, delimiter

is there a way to split a vimscript string with multiple delimiters? I know for example this will split the string by every `'/'`:

`split('C:/test/blub\bla\bla\bla.txt', '/')`.

But is there a way to split the string with multiple delimiters?

For example: `split('C:/test/blub\bla\bla\bla.txt', ['/', '\'])`

To split the string by every `'/'` and `'\'`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` takes a regular expression pattern, so, using a character class (`[...]`):

```
split('C:/test/blub\bla\bla\bla.txt', '[/\\]') # double backslash in pattern
```

or using alternation (`...\|...`):

```
split('C:/test/blub\bla\bla\bla.txt', '/\|\')
```